# Where can I apply for a Portuguese visa as a resident of Scotland?

Tags: visas, uk, scotland, portugal, vietnamese-citizens

I heard that in order to apply for Portugal visa while living in Scotland, I have to do it via the consulate in Manchester, even though the consulate in London is easier to reach. However I cannot find any information to confirm this on the Internet. I tried to call the consulate but they didn't pick up the phone. Hence I wonder if anyone can confirm that information for me.

I'm Vietnamese citizen currently living in the UK on a student visa.

Comment: What is your nationality?

Comment: In addition to your citizenship, what residency do you hold?

Comment: I'm Vietnamese currently living in the UK with a student visa

Comment: +1 In spite of all the criticism and comments, I think the question is fine. The OP obviously understands the rules and is not asking whether he or she needs a visa or can apply for it from the UK so citizenship and residency are not particularly relevant. The problem is that the website of the Portuguese embassy in London is extremely unclear on the shape of the consular districts and the respective responsibilities of the various consulates.

Comment: @Relaxed Their *particular* citizenship is not relevant, but the way they had worded the question could have, in my opinion, led people to assume they were a UK citizen, in which case they wouldn't need a visa for Portugal. I just asked for a little more information so I could edit it into the question and make sure no-one read it wrong. I'm not really sure where you got "all the criticism" from, unless there are some comments which have since been deleted.

Comment: @Relaxed Perhaps I was a little over-cautious, but in my experience it never hurts to give *more* information. If I had *not* thought the question was fine, I would have flagged it.

Comment: @starplusplus It's just that four ‘close’ vote plus two comments asking for information to verify the premise of the question felt like criticism to me. It's true that we got mistaken questions from British citizens before but that one seemed specific enough to assume the OP had done her research and didn't need generic info on visa requirements.

Comment: It's difficult to confirm or deny, but for what it's worth, the London Embassy page doesn't mention anything like this: http://portuguese-embassy.co.uk/pt/assistencia-consular/servicos-consulares/50.html

Comment: Portugal has an "honorary" consulate in Edinburgh. Perhaps that can do visa issuance? http://portuguese-embassy.co.uk/en/consular-section/consulates-in-united-kingdom/39-consulados-no-reino-unido/20-consulado-honorario-de-edimburgo.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently, I have to apply for the visa in Manchester as I'm living in Scotland. I am sure about it now as they (i.e. the London office) refused to receive my application based on my address.

Even though they have an online booking system, it allowed me to select either Manchester or London office regardless my address, but when I went to the London office, the person, who was in charge of processing the application, told me that I had to go to the Manchester one.

Comment: The Manchester Team also does consular visits to Edinburgh, Glasgow, and now recently Aberdeen at various times in the year. Information and appointments for these is only available by emailing them. Be patient as they will only reply when they have the dates ready. Also bear in mind, only certain services are provided at these clinics. I've used it a few times myself.

Comment: Dates can be found [on Portal of the Portuguese Communities](https://www.portaldascomunidades.mne.pt/pt/rede-consular/europa/reino-unido#consulado-geral-de-portugal-em-manchester) but appointments are by email only. Too late to edit my previous comment :)

Answer (score 8):

The Portuguese system works a bit differently...

All visa applications lodged in the UK need to made online at their [Application Portal](http://www.secomunidades.pt/vistos/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=171&Itemid=14&lang=en).

As part of the procedure you will have the opportunity to schedule your appointment request and the site will tell you which locations and dates are available.  Edinburgh, being an honorary consulate, does not have the credentials to issue visas.  The choices in England are London and Manchester.

You should study their guidance (linked from the portal site) and be sure to take your original documents plus a copy of each (also your photographs).

They have an background information page [here](http://www.sef.pt/portal/V10/EN/aspx/legislacao/index.aspx?id_linha=4191&menu_position=4133#0).

In researching this answer I spoke with the Vice Consul at The Consulate-General of Portugal in London.  She emphasized in the most emphatic terms that you should not purchase travel tickets until AFTER your interview.

In the event you have further questions you can contact the Serviço de Estrangeiros e Fronteiras (SEF) at sef@sef.pt

Comment: It should be noted that an online system allows you to choose either London or Manchester offices regardless your current address. However, if you choose the London office while living in Scotland, they will not accept your application when you come and submit them.

Comment: @LongThai sounds like somebody at the consulate didn't get the word. I hope you complained.

Answer (score 4):

I've emailed the [Portuguese consulate in Manchester](http://portuguese-embassy.co.uk/en/consular-section/consulates-in-united-kingdom/39-consulados-no-reino-unido/17-consulado-geral-de-manchester.html) and received the following reply:

> **The Consulate General of Portugal in Manchester jurisdiction areas are:**
>
> - East Midlands — Derbyshire and Nottinghamshire, Leicestershire,    Rutland and Northamptonshire, Lincolnshire
> - West Midlands — Herefordshire, Worcestershire and Warwickshire,    Shropshire and Staffordshire
> - North East England — Northumberland, County Durham, Tyne and Wear,    Teeside, Wearside, and Tyneside
> - North West England — Cumbria, Lancashire, Greater Manchester,    Merseyside and Cheshire
> - Yorkshire and the Humber — Yorkshire, Humberside
> - Isle of Man
> - Wales
> - Scotland
> - Northern Ireland
>
> **If you live outside of these areas please contact the Consulate General of Portugal in London**.

Therefore you must apply in Manchester, unfortunately, as correctly indicated by the consulate employee.