# Indian passport holder living in Scotland, travelling to portugal for vacations

Tags: visas, schengen, uk, indian-citizens, portugal

I am living in Edinburgh and hold a 5-year work permit in the UK.  I want to travel to Portugal for 15 days.  I hold an Indian passport; can you please tell me if I need to apply for a visa? if so, how can I apply for it and for the biometric test and other formalities for the visa?  Do I have to travel outside Edinburgh?

Comment: Yes, you need a visa. You must apply in Manchester.  See http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/47284/where-can-i-apply-for-a-portuguese-visa-as-a-resident-of-scotland.

Answer (score 5):

You are an Indian national with a 5 year UK Tier 2 visa and want to visit Portugal.

Indian nationals need a Schengen visa before they can visit any of the member states, including Portugal.  Having a UK visa is certainly helpful in determining your risk, but it has no value outside of the UK.  By air, the carrier will not allow you to board and if you travel by land you could face fines and other sanctions.

Indian nationals who apply from the UK need to show that they are normally resident there. In your case this would be your T2 visa because it was issued for a period longer than six months.

There is a related article about the mechanics of applying here [Where can I apply for a Portuguese visa as a resident of Scotland?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/47284/where-can-i-apply-for-a-portuguese-visa-as-a-resident-of-scotland)